# How does js regular expression match comma-separated content that does not contain ()

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write `match`?
How does js regular expression match comma-separated content that 
does not contain `()`?
How to write this regular expression?

For example:

```js
var str = "123(xxxx),456,dd(hh(xxxx,xxxx),ww(xxxx,xxxx))";
var newstr = str.split(/match/);
console.log(newstr)
```

Expected result:

```
["123(xxxx)","456","dd(hh(xxxx,xxxx),ww(xxxx,xxxx))"];
```

Comment: You should add some input and expected output examples. Also search for online regex services, they will give you a simple interface to test your matches and most of the good ones also list all the various options.

Answer (score 0):

To split on commas: `([\w|\d|\(\)]+)`. 
Loop on the output cases, and to filter parentheses: `^((?!(\(|\))).)*$`.